# Задержка при наведении меню

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Здравствуйте. Есть меню, при наведение на него появляется выпадающее вертикальное меню. Только это происходит моментально. Хотелось бы добавить задержку в 2-3 секунды.

К сожалению мне не удалось все это красиво оформить в `JSFiddle`. Объемный CSS +возможно есть `JS`.

Ссылка на меню (вертикальное, категории товаров) http://demo.cs-cart.ru/stores/137929/.

Спасибо большое.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо добавить свойства к CSS классам:

```
.ty-menu__submenu-items {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.no-touch .ty-menu__item:hover .ty-menu__submenu-items, .is-hover-menu .ty-menu__submenu-items {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all linear 1s;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно. А как убрать эффект перехода?

Comment: Можно использовать нелинейную функцию перехода transition: all cubic-bezier(1, -0.3, 1, -0.35) 0.3s;

Answer (score 0):

```css
nav a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  line-height: 2em;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav li ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 1s step-end;
}

nav li li {
  display: block;
}

nav a:hover {
  background: silver;
}

nav li:hover > ul {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1.3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li><li>
      <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2.3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2.4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```